# I can’t get Contentful connected to my site

Tags: javascript, curl, static, blogs, contentful

So, I've only ever used WordPress, but I decided to build my site from scratch so I'm free to do whatever I want with my site. I'm a new developer and I just heard about Contentful.

I like the sound of it and I want to use it to build my blog, but I've been following their instructions and looking up external tutorials for 8 hours and I can't get it to work.

Contentful recommends using cURL, but I don't understand where to put that code or how to tell my site to generate a new page for every blog post once it's there. I've also tried the JavaScript instructions and that failed. There are like 6 other language options on Contentful, but I'm not familiar with any of them.

Sorry for my ignorance, I'd love any insight (and especially explicit instructions) you can give me on the best way to set up Contentful to semi-automatically push blog posts to my blog page.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

With Contentful, you can use any front-end framework of your choice. Contentful will help you with managing your content, and you have the flexibility to select the language and framework you want to use for your front end.

If you want to quickly get started and are already familiar with the React ecosystem, you should check out [Next.js](https://www.contentful.com/nextjs-starter-guide/) or [Gatsby](https://www.contentful.com/gatsby-starter-guide/) quick start guides.